# USB dongle for remote control doesn't wake up

Tags: usb, sleep-mode, wakeup, raspberry-pi-zero, dongle

A bit stumped on this one, hoping any of you fine people can assist...

I have a 2.4g remote control with a USB dongle that I'd like to use on a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W running Raspbian Lite 32bit. When plugged in, it's detected and works fine. When left without any activity for a little while (haven't timed it exactly, but 8-10 hours or so) the dongle goes into sleep mode, and pressing the remote control doesn't wake it up again.

I have tried a Logitech dongle on the Zero, and that wakes up just fine, and the remote control dongle also wakes up just fine on a Windows PC, so it seems to be this combination Zero/dongle that won't let it wake up.

Have tried usbreset, uhubctl etc to no avail. When doing a usbhid-dump, it shows me the info even when in sleep, but it's non-responsive to keypresses nonetheless.

Any pointers in any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: wrong site, as this is not a programming question. probably better to post on [su] or [raspberrypi.se]

Comment: Alrighty, will do - thanks!